# Difference between MySQL NOW() and PHP date('c')

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

What is the difference between them? If I use them both on my local machine (windows, xampp), the difference between them is one hour. Why?

Comment: Does mysql and php have different time settings then?

Comment: That's most likely the case, but it's a setting that you can change.

Comment: tips : use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably having different timezone for PHP and MySql. You need to set the same timezone for both to get the date time without any difference

Comment: I know how to change timezone in PHP in script, is it also possible with mysql?

Comment: @BadrHari: Yes, It is possible.

Comment: Thank you, found it already: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Comment: @BadrHari: Note that This actually does not change the timezone of mysql, the values stored in the database still having the old timezone, This just convert the date according to given timezone while SELECT'ING record

Answer (score 2):

there's no difference, but you might have configured different timezones for both (or one of them doesn't use daylight saving time). please check your...

- [php configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php)
- [mysql configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html)

Comment: Makes sense, I have to stick with using only one then.